# How do I get Cloudcannon image inputs to work with Hugo image processing?

Tags: hugo, cloudcannon

I'm trying to use Cloudcannon as a CMS for a Hugo-based website. For some of my content types, I use Hugo's image processing, which means I store those images that need to be processed under `assets/` rather than `static/`.

Cloudcannon allows for image inputs to be configured with a custom upload directory, which I need to go to the correct subdirectory of `assets/images/` for each content type. That works fine--the images are uploaded to the right location. The problem is that then the frontmatter path for the image includes the `assets/` part of the directory path, which doesn't work for Hugo.

My configuration is as follows, allowing images uploaded for different content types to go in different subdirectories of `assets/images/`.

```
collections_config:
  news:
    schemas:
      default:
        path: schemas/news.md
        name: News post
    path: content/english/news
    _inputs:
      image:
        type: image
        options:
          uploads_dir: assets/images/news
  clients:
    schemas:
      default:
        path: schemas/client.md
        name: Client listing
    path: content/english/clients
    _inputs:
      image:
        type: image
        options:
          uploads_dir: assets/images/clients
```

Is there any way to set the fontmatter output path to exclude `assets/`? Maybe there's a separate option from `uploads_dir` I haven't found?

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a static path here. The static path is used when uploading new files, but is not saved as part of the path for the front matter field. It's set globally, and defaults to your Hugo `--staticDir` command line option (defaults to `static`).

Here's how you would set it up for your code example:

Create or add to `/cloudcannon.config.yml`:

```yaml
paths:
  uploads: assets/images/[collection]
  static: assets
```

Uploading a new file called `cat.png` on an input in the news collection here is sent to: `/assets/images/news/cat.png`. The value saved in the front matter is `/images/news/cat.png`.

I've also set a global `uploads` path here with the `[collection]` placeholder, which will have the same result as your `uploads_dir` options - and you won't have to set it multiple times.